# How to display the property of an object in a directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The object looks like this:

```
{"objectId":"5666759200b09f85717e8954","name":"TestNewSunflower"...
```

The directive:

```
.directive('breadcrumb', function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'EA',
                template: '<ol class="breadcrumb">' +
                    '<li><a href="#/building/{{building.objectId}}">{{building}}</a></li>' +
                    '</ol>',
                scope: {
                    building: "@"
```

How I'm using it:

```
<breadcrumb building="{{building}}"></breadcrumb>
```

But I'm unable to display the `name` property.

I tried `building.name`, `building[name]` but nothing works.

What's the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `@` in scope, value will consider as text.

If you wanna use as an object,you have to parse with `JSON.parse` or `angular.parse`

Instead use `building` as two way.

Like this

```
building: "="
```

Then your html will be

```
<breadcrumb building="building"></breadcrumb>
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<breadcrumb building="building"></breadcrumb>
```